# Javascript confirmation cancel button issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list with few action links on it. On click of an Action Link a Javascript Confirmation Dialog is opening.

If user selects Yes, it is calls Controller Action Method. But in the Confirmation Dialog Box, a message is coming: "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs".

If I check this option, it goes to the Action method even if I click No.

How to prevent this message from appearing?

Comment: don't use confirm/alert/prompt dialogs - make your own or use a search engine to find a suitable library

Comment: @JaromandaX Please suggest any library. Shall I use jQuery?

Comment: I wouldn't suggest a library as that is not what SO is about and I write my own code ... however, alertify is ok though no longer maintained